# How to use nodejs modules in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, browserify, fs

I try to create an app that converts files in the browser. Locally I use gltf-pipeline for example. Right now I am building the web app with react. Unfortunately I can't import gltf-pipeline. It seems there are some problems with fs-extra. I can't use this module either. So my question is how to be able to use nodejs modules in browser? I already tried to browserifiy it but that didn't work.

Thank you for you help.

--

EDIT:

If I import the modules directly with:

```
import gltfPipeline from 'gltf-pipeline'
```

I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'native' of undefined
./node_modules/gltf-pipeline/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/fs/index.js
// fs.realpath.native only available in Node v9.2+
> 107 | if (typeof fs.realpath.native === 'function') {
  108 |   exports.realpath.native = u(fs.realpath.native)
  109 | }
```

If I import the generated file using browserify I receive this:

```
./src/Components/Page/Models/Converter/gltfPipeline.js
  Line 2:99:         'reqqq' is not defined                                                 no-undef
  Line 2:398:        'reqqq' is not defined                                                 no-undef
  Line 41:1:         Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 41:124:       'define' is not defined                                                no-undef
  Line 41:135:       'define' is not defined                                                no-undef
  Line 41:159:       Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 41:251:       Unexpected use of 'self'                                               no-restricted-globals
  Line 41:260:       Unexpected use of 'self'                                               no-restricted-globals
  Line 41:415:       '_dereq_' is not defined                                               no-undef
  Line 41:715:       '_dereq_' is not defined                                               no-undef
  Line 5373:27:      Unexpected use of 'self'                                               no-restricted-globals
  Line 5373:50:      Unexpected use of 'self'                                               no-restricted-globals
  Line 5790:208:     Unexpected use of 'self'                                               no-restricted-globals
  Line 5790:232:     Unexpected use of 'self'                                               no-restricted-globals
  Line 5790:277:     Unexpected use of 'self'                                               no-restricted-globals
  Line 5790:286:     Unexpected use of 'self'                                               no-restricted-globals
  Line 5791:93:      Unexpected use of 'self'                                               no-restricted-globals
  Line 5791:116:     Unexpected use of 'self'                                               no-restricted-globals
  Line 5831:2808:    'read' is not defined                                                  no-undef
  Line 5831:2964:    'readbuffer' is not defined                                            no-undef
  Line 5831:2984:    'read' is not defined                                                  no-undef
  Line 5831:3091:    'scriptArgs' is not defined                                            no-undef
  Line 5831:3214:    'quit' is not defined                                                  no-undef
  Line 5831:3238:    Unexpected use of 'print'                                              no-restricted-globals
  Line 5831:3314:    Unexpected use of 'print'                                              no-restricted-globals
  Line 5831:3377:    'printErr' is not defined                                              no-undef
  Line 5831:3386:    Unexpected use of 'print'                                              no-restricted-globals
  Line 5831:3486:    Unexpected use of 'self'                                               no-restricted-globals
  Line 5835:16223:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

...

I followed this guide: https://hackernoon.com/using-core-node-js-modules-in-react-native-apps-64acd4d07140.
After generating the js file there are already some errors showing in vs code.

Comment: Browserify didn't work? What was the problem

Comment: Can you share any code.

Comment: I updated my post with some errors.